# Migrate Maven-plugins to Gradle: What happens with plugin configurations?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to migrate my build process from Maven to Gradle. I was wondering about what happens to the configuration-tag.
For example, i got this code block in the pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <!-- https://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/index.html -->
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-minify</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <jsSourceDir>static/js/app</jsSourceDir>
                        <jsSourceFiles>
                            <jsSourceFile>javascript.js</jsSourceFile>
                            <jsSourceFile>wiki-script.js</jsSourceFile>
                            <jsSourceFile>sidr/sidr.js</jsSourceFile>
                        </jsSourceFiles>
                        <webappTargetDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</webappTargetDir>
                        <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>minify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I know that Gradle doesn't have this plugin. But if i want Gradle to do something that produces the same result, i don't really know how. Do i need tasks for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to either:

1. Find an equivalent Gradle plugin that offers similar capabilities as `minify-maven-plugin`
2. Create your own plugin: [Developing Custom Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html)

From a quick Google search, it seems the `org.padler.gradle.minify` plugin offers the same capability the Maven one does.

- https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.padler.gradle.minify
- https://github.com/616slayer616/gradle-minify-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I found that one too. But i have like half a dozen of other plugins with the configuration-tag, for example `<configuration> ...... </configuration>`. So actually my question was what options do i have with gradle to accomplish a similar effect, like how do i configure a plugin in Gradle. Not how to create my own plugin, but how to add some extras to an existing plugin.

EDIT:
Nevermind, i found more information regarding the configuration on the plugins github, But thank you nevertheless